# Xcode editor autoscrolls to the top of the page

Tags: ios, xcode

Lately I have been experiencing strange behaviour in Xcode, after some period of coding it begins to autoscroll to the top of the current code page, and it wont let me scroll, if I am persistent in trying to scroll, my whole code disappears and the whole thing looks like this:[image]

I am currently using Xcode 4.6.3 but the issue is also present in v. >= 5.0. Has anybody came across this type of problem. Please help, it is driving me mad.

EDIT:
I managed to get my code back by hiding and showing right panel in xCode, it seams to rebuilt the page, if U see in left corner of my screenshot there is a true line number but it is the only line in my editor, until I hide/show right panel then the code returns, after that if I continue scrolling it disappears again...

EDIT 2: Ok now I experienced another thing, my code just breaks, it turns in a bunch of letters scrambled across the screen, like code editor forgets all formatting and line breaks and just shows the code in some way. Again hide/show of right panel fixes the problem but just for a while. 
The problem occurs when I make a syntax error or when intellisense offers me some autocomplete code and I don't complete that line in that exact moment. After that it's all down the hill. I'll try to capture the broken code and I'll post it when I do...

EDIT 3: I managed to capture the broken code so that you can see what I am up against:[image]

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: no, app store version whit its normal updates

Comment: Check Console for messages when the issue happens. Disable all launch agents, login items, disconnect all peripherals, quit all the other apps, see if it helps.

Comment: Is anything leaning against a key on the keyboard, or anything like that?

Comment: No nothing is leaning on my keyboard. I tried total system and xCode reboot, it helps, but just for a little while...

Comment: I'd also check if any of the accessibility options are on in the system prefs.

Comment: I don't think I explained it correctly, this does'n look like something is doing this, some plugin or xCode feature, it looks like code is breaking and disappearing, it looks like a bug not a feature... So I don't think that the problem is in add ons...

Comment: Check for Apple Remote or Bluetooth mouse signals (both can be disabled in system settings).

Comment: I don't understand, how can that affect code editor in xCode, I don't have this problem in all of my projects, only in some files, like he remembered something that he cannot process...

Comment: @AntonijoDev I don't think its a bug. You are the only one experiencing this.

Comment: So? I didn't know that definition of a bug is something that doesn't work in at least 2 or more cases...

Comment: @AntonijoDev What I meant was that It's not a common Xcode bug and probably related to something else on your system. Looks like a malware if you ask me...oh wait.. you're on a mac.. I experienced something kinda similar when I had Vim plugin installed and didn't know how to use it which brings us to my first question that you replied with No.